# MFC App crashes on call to CWinApp::OnOpenDocument() or CDocTemplate::OnOpenDocument()

Tags: mfc

I have an MFC application that crashes when the CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile() or CDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile() methods are called. The odd thing is that this only happens when the application is installed to either C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files(x86) and is not launched as an Administrator.  If the application is launched with Administrator privileges from these folders, it runs fine. Also, if the application is installed to a folder other than these folders it runs ok without Administrator privileges.

Tried changing the call from CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile to CDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile.  Both exhibit the same problem. Also tried installing on different computers. But all exhibit the same problem.  The computers are running Windows 10, as this is the OS required by our company.

Comment: What happens if you debug this with the debugger?

Comment: Actually I suspect your code tries to create a file in the folder where the .exe is. This creation will fail if the .exe is in C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files(x86) (unless the code is running as admin) and this failure probably leads to the crash somehow.

Comment: That's the thing. It works fine with the debugger. That's why it wasn't detected until it was installed on a user's computer.  And I could run it outside the debugger.

Comment: I thought it might be creating a file as well. But this seems to be happening withing the MFC Framework. I think this because I put AfxMessageBoxes just before the CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile and the entry to the CDocument::OnOpenDocument methods. The message box before the CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile is hit. But the app crashes before the CDocument::OnOpenDocument call. I'm not sure what happens between these two calls. Not aware if MFC is trying to either write a file or registry entry.

Comment: I'd add some logging to your program, which will help you to pinpoint the location where the crash happens.